# Sqlite result return OK on insert but record is not there is database

Tags: sqlite

This is a insert function and I am trying to insert some records in database.

but in b/w it will not store the record in data

Here sqlite3_step and sqlite3_finalize return OK but still record is not there in database.

what else shall I verify for this issue?

```
  /*Table update for past event*/
void PE_tableUpdate(sqlite3 * PE_db,int nTransLen, char * cTransID, int nDiagLen,char    * cDiagID, int nAlarmID, int nPktCounter, int nEventNo, char * cStTime,    char * cEndTime, int nECGMode)
{
char * PE_sqlquery;
sqlite3_stmt * PE_stmt;
int PE_Result;
char Up_stat[5] = {'N'};
char Up_stat1[5]= {'D'};

/*Write SQL Query */
PE_sqlquery = "insert into PasteventsTble (TransID,DiagID,AlarmID,PktCounter,EventNo,StrtTime,EndTime,UploadStatus,ECGMode) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
/*Run SQL Query*/
PE_Result =  sqlite3_prepare_v2 (PE_db, PE_sqlquery, strlen (PE_sqlquery) + 1, &PE_stmt, NULL);
DB_DBG_PRINTF("AlarmCountDBDEBUGStart2 PE_Result:%d",PE_Result);

if((nECGMode     ==  _DEVICE_ARRHYTHMIA_MODE) && (nAlarmID != 100))
    nPktCounter  = nPktCounter - OFFSET_ARRYTHMIC;

if(nPktCounter < 0)
    nPktCounter = 0;

/*Load into DB*/
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_text(PE_stmt,SQL_TRANSID_INDEX,cTransID,nTransLen,NULL);
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_text(PE_stmt,SQL_DIAGID_INDEX,cDiagID,nDiagLen,NULL);
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_int(PE_stmt,SQL_ALARM_INDEX,nAlarmID);
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_int(PE_stmt,SQL_PKTCOUNTER_INDEX,nPktCounter);
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_int(PE_stmt,SQL_EVENTNO_INDEX,nEventNo);
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_text(PE_stmt,SQL_ST_TIME_INDEX,cStTime,HRTIME_NO_OF_CHAR,NULL);
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_text(PE_stmt,SQL_END_TIME_INDEX,cEndTime,HRTIME_NO_OF_CHAR,NULL);
PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_int(PE_stmt,SQL_ECGMODE_INDEX,nECGMode);

/* Check if the alarm has already been uploaded or not */
if((DOCTOR_SNAPSHOT == nAlarmID) || (nAlarmID != prevAlarmID) )
{
    PE_Result   = sqlite3_bind_text(PE_stmt,SQL_UPLOAD_INDEX,Up_stat,1,NULL);
    prevAlarmID = nAlarmID;
    DB_DBG_PRINTF("AlarmCountDBDEBUGStart3 PE_Result:%d",PE_Result);
}
else
{
    PE_Result = sqlite3_bind_text(PE_stmt,SQL_UPLOAD_INDEX,Up_stat1,1,NULL);
    DB_DBG_PRINTF("AlarmCountDBDEBUGStart4 PE_Result:%d",PE_Result);
}

/*Step into*/
PE_Result = sqlite3_step(PE_stmt);
DB_DBG_PRINTF("AlarmCountDBDEBUGStart PE_Result5:%d",PE_Result);

DB_DBG_PRINTF("AlarmCountDBDEBUGStart Stored");

PE_Result = sqlite3_finalize(PE_stmt);

DB_DBG_PRINTF("AlarmCountDBDEBUGStart PE_Result6:%d",PE_Result);

DB_DBG_PRINTF("PE_tableUpdated");
 }
```

Comment: Any chance you're running the code in a transaction and didn't commit?

Comment: ya I am not doing commit the database. how to commit the database. Can you please edit my function ?

Comment: If you have not executed some `BEGIN`, you are using automatic transactions, which are committed automatically.

Comment: What are the logged `PE_Result`s?

Comment: PE_Results is OK .i.e 0.

Comment: I am accessing the same database from Android Java layer. Do i need to synchronise